# Can we use & in url?

Tags: url, uri

Can we use "&" in a url ? or should **"and"** be used?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can use it plain in your URL path like this:

```
http://example.com/Alice&Bob
```

Only if you want to use it in the query you need to encode it with `%26`:

```
http://example.com/?arg=Alice%26Bob
```

Otherwise it would be interpreted as argument separator when interpreted as [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

See [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more details.

Comment: I hope this is true: it would make the difference between a great and a poor answer. In-line dated citations from *RFC3986* may make this superb

Answer (score 9):

An URL is generally in the form

```
scheme://host/some/path/to/file?query1=value&query2=value
```

So it is not advisable to use it in an URL unless you want to use it for parameters. Otherwise you should percent escape it using %26, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/hello%26world
```

This results in the path being submitted as hello&world. There are other characters which must be escaped when used out of context in an URL. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for a list.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I just read the part about encoding in the RFC you linked in your answer. But if I understood this correctly it seems that http://example.com/Alice&Bob and http://example.com/Alice%26Bob are not considered equivalent and may be interpreted differently by an application (which is though not the case with HTTP as you pointed out).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're appending variables to the query string, encode it.

Answer (score 2):

encode '&' with `&amp;` (this answer is based on your use of tags)

If you are asking what to use "&" or "and" when registering the name of your URL, I would use "and".

EDIT: As mentioned in comments "& is an HTML character entity and not a URI character entity. By putting that into a URI you still have the ampersand character and additional extraneous characters." I started answering before fully understanding your question.

Comment: &amp; is an HTML character entity and not a URI character entity.  By putting that into a URI you still have the ampersand character and additional extraneous characters.

Comment: *Face palm* Right, posted before thinking that through. Down vote as appropriate.

Comment: Well, you have to use &amp; in a URL inside a link, e.g: <a href="http://example.com/x&amp;y">. You are correct in that case. (SO is messing up my example,but you get the idea.)

Comment: s/&amp;/%26/ and you're golden