# Is "&" character inside url segment allowed?

Tags: seo, url-rewriting

Is "&" character in url allowed? What is the impact to url if it's illegal and is present. I'm looking for an answer from an SEO standpoint.

Example:

rootdomain.com/Black&Decker/products

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693595

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's permitted (amongst other places) as part of separating specified parameters in a GET e.g.

```
http://example.com/query?a=1&b=2
```

defines `a=1` *and* `b=2`.

Note that & is a *reserved* character under RFC3986. See [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) on percent encoding for more details.

Comment: On top of this, if when it's in HTML, you have to escape it: /query?a=1&amp;b=2

Comment: Reading RFC 3986 it seems to me, that '&' is permitted *everywhere* after the host name and the first slash. The characters with special meaning are solely '?' and '#'.

Comment: Notice also that while you have to escape it in HTML, you _can't_ escape it in JavaScript. So you have to remember `<a href="a&amp;b">` but `location.href='a&b';`

Comment: @Gumbo - the answer above is meant to illustrate to the OP that & is allowed in a URL - not to be a canonical definition of where & can/can't be used. Not sure why you've indicated Zarel's comment to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to have an `&` in a folder/file name. However it's quite likely to break somewhere for someone so it's best to avoid it. You could use a `+` character, the word "and" or just omit the join altogether (i.e. `BlackDecker` or `Black-Decker`).

From an SEO point of view, any of those would be fine since they contain the keywords, and search engines generally ignore symbol characters in searches.