# email address in the url

Tags: email, url-rewriting, web-applications

I am passing the email address as part of the url,

for ex.  http://example.com/hello/user@hotmail.com

but, when being passed to the application controller it is changed to " user%40hotmail.com ".

I can't seem to understand this special character escaping; confusion.
please help me explain the problem here, and also what can I do to fix it.

I am using python's "webapp"  web application framework.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814700/http-url-allowed-characters-in-parameter-names, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828958/is-character-inside-url-segment-allowed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being URL encoded.

You'll need to decode it.

Comment: I think i probably should use, urllib2.ubquote("email%40domain.com")

this seems to work

Answer (score 1):

`@` turns into `%40` because of [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) commonly known as url encoding.

Without knowing exactly how the code is being used, it would be worth while to look at [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) utility functions for decoding. Here is one for example,

- [`unquote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

> Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.