# htaccess no working fine with some character

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

This is my url rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/?$ controller/$1/$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

working fine with :`http://yii.abc.com/category/Grand-Opening`
but no working with : `http://yii.abc.com/category/I'm-sorry` and

```
http://yii.abc.com/category/Wedding-&-ROM
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't included characters `'` and `&` in your character class.

You can fix it by including them like this.

**Regex:** `^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)\/(['&a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)\/?$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS2gA6/2)**

Comment: I have already change to your regex,
now working fine with :`http://yii.abc.com/category/I'm-sorry`
but at `http://yii.abc.com/category/Wedding-&-ROM`
I echo $_GET['id'] get `Wedding-` only, cannot get full string

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/?$` This is your regex. Mine is different sir.

Comment: 'http://yii.abc.com/category/Wedding-&-ROM' I echo $_GET['id'] get 'Wedding- only', cannot get full string

Comment: You should know that `&` means variable separation in URL. It won't be accessed by `$_GET` because it's an array of `endpoints` separated by `&` so it's not recognized by `$_GET` as part of variable.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693595/can-we-use-in-url).

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w=-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ controller/$1/$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```

Using `B` flag is the key here to be able to pass whole `Wedding-&-ROM` as `GET` parameter.

Comment: That's the real mazic of B :) +1