# C# - WebAPI - Ampersand in url

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI (.Net 4.8) act as a proxy between clients and a document API.

These documents sometimes had "&" in their ident (It's bad but I'm not responsible of this document API)

When I try to get a document :
https://localhost:44875/ged/Ident1&/content

My WebAPI respond 400 Bad Request :
Web API: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

I know the trick and I tried

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,&amp;" />
  </system.web>
```

Or I tried

```
<system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Nothing happened... Ampersand still not allowed, so i'm confused.

Any idea ?

EDIT :
I had a bad comprehension of requestPathInvalidCharacters function.
If I want & to be valid, I have to suppress it in the requestPathInvalidCharacters list.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Like Microsoft Sharepoint or any other WebDAV sites that host documents: you can't do it. The documents can't contain `?`, `&` and `#`.

Comment: Well, they can contain those characters, but your request can't. I recommend [URL encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-7.0) your requests, and then on the server [URL decoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=net-7.0) the query parameters to a "proper" string

Comment: If you tried the "usual" fixes and they did not work, we will need a [mcve] to debug this further.

Comment: @MindSwipe: It [seems to be legal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1693732/87698) in the "path" part of the URL.

Comment: If you want `&` to be **valid**, why do you explicitly **include** it in the requestPath**Invalid**Characters list?